# Htaccess 301 redirects after switching language detection method

Tags: i18n-l10n, redirection, .htaccess

We have a multilingual Drupal installation with a domain for each language. Like this:

- domainexample.com
- domainexample.no
- domainexample.de
- etc...

We want to switch to a single domain and use domain prefix instead:

- domainexample.com/en
- domainexample.com/no
- domainexample.com/de
- etc...

Settings this up through Drupal administration is no hassle - the problem is that the old domains should redirect to the new one.
My guess is that this should be possible with some sneaky htaccess. I'm no expert here however.
I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainexample.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainexample.de$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domainexample.com/de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...which works for the frontpage - but not for the subpages. They get redirected to this 404 page: domainexample.com/de/index.php.

How can this be solved?

/Morten

Comment: The `$` signals the _end_ of a string, so working only for the homepage is correct for what you currently have. You want `^domainexample.de` or `^domainexample.de/?.*$` etc

Comment: Thank You for Your response Clive. Much appreciated. However I still get redirected to a 404 domainexample.com/de/index.php no matter what subpage I try to access.

Comment: My guess is that the htaccess file sees the path before it is URL rewritten as domainexample.com/index.php?q=mypath. When I redirects things go wrong because it takes the entire "index.php?q=mypath" and tries to attach it to the new url.That might be why I'm redirected to: domainexample.com/de/index.php ... it's just a guess though.